# Run executable in DOS from memory

Tags: c, exe, executable, dos, entry-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int fsize;
    char *string;
    void (*f)(void);


    FILE *f1 = fopen("NONAME.EXE", "rb");
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(f1);
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_SET);

    string = malloc(fsize + 1);
    fread(string, 1, fsize, f1);
    fclose(f1);

    string = string + 0x14;


    f = string;
    printf("jumping...\n");
    f();
    printf("after...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code for execute exe file. Both exe compiled and run in turbo c 2.0 with DosBox.

And this program just freeze after call f();

What things could be wrong?

Comment: .EXE files have fixups. (.COM dont) .PE executables (and COFF and ELF) have even more difficult loader needs. For .COM executables this could be done with some assemble magic (setting CS=DS= loaded segment, and IP=0x100, IIRC. [but this is all outdated stuff]

Comment: Definitely don't use turbo c 2.0 for anything, unless you have the the box that includes the manual, then it's good for a door stop.

Comment: @jwdonahue why? What should I use under DOS?

Comment: @wildplasser what about entry point in exe, it's fixed on 14h position or not? I can't find software that correct showing 16bit exe headers.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov There are books about that (around 1985) You could try Peter Norton (the pink shirt book) or Ralph Brown's "interrupt list" (which must still be available online) Anyway: .exe are "relocatable", and there is a preamble (postamble?) in the file with the locations to fixup. (and their segments, I think)

Comment: .EXE is basically a file-format. It is rather easy: just hexdump the stuff. From the top of my head: `MZ` executable:  first page with pointers/sizes to sections. Next: the sections. That's all.